# How to keep an element in a ratio of 4:3 while perfectly center in the screen and responsive?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<body>
    <feature></feature>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above feature I want to have an image (background-size:cover) so it fill exactly 4:3 ratio and be on the center of the screen at all time (and doesn't exceed either the height or width of the screen).

I tried the following stylesheet:

```
feature {
    padding: 40% 50% 40% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -40%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    background: url('horse1.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This has a problem when the screen is very wide, the height will exceed the height of the screen. `max-height` doesn't seem to limit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somethinghere's solution isn't bad but when the screen's width is greater than its height, the image will leave 20% of white space on top and bottom.

Instead you can try this:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 75vw;
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 133.33vh;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top:0;bottom:0;
left:0;right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with percentages, as a matter of fact, I would explicitly use percentages to maintain the aspect ratio.

```css
html,body { min-height: 100%; height: 100%; }

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 90vmin;
}

div:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding: 0 0 75%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the media query for aspect ratios to determine when the page has changed aspect - this might not work depending on what else you have on the page but it can be very useful on background images.

Example one (limits width when height is below aspect ratio)

```css
.feature {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/400x300') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.feature::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 75%; 
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) { 
  .feature {
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
  }
  
  .feature::before {
    padding-top: 0; 
    max-height: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
<div>
```

Example 2 (loses aspect when width is greater than 4/3 aspect)

Remove line `background-size: contain;`

Answer (score -1):

First of, you *cannot* accomplish this with percentages. To keep the appropriate aspect ratio, you need to use a unit that is the same size in *both* dimensions, so use something like `vmin` or `vmax` to accomplish this. The same for your centering using `margin` and percentages - those percentages don't have a universal meaning, they are related to the wrapping box. Here a `translate` is useful, as those percentages represent the size of the *box* (1--% is the full width of the box), not its parent.

The following will keep the aspect ratio of 5x4 through your paddings (although it might be better to just use `width: 100vmin` and `height: 80vmin` in this case). Note that your paddings are not actually a 4x3 ratio, but you can easily figure that out at this point.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

feature {
    padding: 40vmin 50vmin 40vmin 50vmin;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: url(http://placehold.it/100x80);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<feature></feature>
```

Comment: Why in the world can't you accomplish this with percentages?

Comment: @adam Because percentages are _based on the parent size_, so they cannot reliably keep a certain aspect ratio for an element, as the final parent size is the viewport size.

Comment: That's right - look at my answer and you'll see that you can use a pseudo element with a percentage.

Comment: @adam That's only true because the parent size is a _determined_ unit. If you make the parent a percentage size your box will start distorting just as well. So you cannot _solely_ rely on percentages.

Comment: But that's what the OP wanted - not to exceed the width or the height - so you use something like width: `90vmin` and you're done.

Comment: My bad, semantics I guess that you can't **solely** rely on percentages - but whenever I hear the term aspect ratio, I immediately think 0 height element with a percentage padding.

Comment: @adam Yeah, solely is a _key_ point, but okay. Since the OP only had percentages in there and my answer cuts those out entirely to make it work,  I think its valid to say that it didnt work with percentages. Anyhow, I think neither of our answers are incorrect and both make sense, be it in different ways (never used 0 box with padding for aspect ratio, never thought of it, so at least I learned something!)